# Script for "extracting" subfolders into parent folder

Tags: bash, scripts, directory, mv

This gonna be a little bit tricky, I guess :-)

When I open a terminal in the folder and run a script, that script should:

1. move all content of all subfolders to a top parent folder (recursively)
2. delete all empty folders

Parent folder we are standing in will contain no folders, just content of all of them.

It should work for hidden files and folders as well. It would be immensely useful for house cleaning :-)

I've tried something like:

```
find . -type f -name "*" -depth | xargs mv ./
```

But with no luck.

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: By the way, `-name "*"` means "restrict the search to only files whose names match the wildcard pattern `*` — which is all of them.  In other words, `-name "*"` does nothing and can be left out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest and cleanest way in my opinion would be to use this command:

```
find . -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered {} . \; && find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -r {} +
```

`find` command #1:

- `.`: searches in the current working directory;
- `-type f`: searches for files;
- `-exec [...]`: executes either a command for each result (using `{} [...] \;`) or a command for all the results (using `{} +`);
- `mv --backup=numbered . \;`: moves each result in the current working directory, creating a backup of files with the same filename already in the current working directory;

`find` command #2:

- `.`: searches in the current working directory;
- `-maxdepth 1`: searches only in the first level of the target directory hierarchy;
- `-type d`: searches for directories;
- `-exec [...]`: executes either a command for each result (using `{} [...] \;`) or a command for all the results (using `{} +`);
- `rm -r {} +`: deletes each result;

Test on a test directory hierarchy:

```
user@debian ~/tmp % tree -a
.
├── 1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   └── .hidden
├── 2
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   └── .hidden
└── 3
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    ├── file3
    └── .hidden

3 directories, 12 files
user@debian ~/tmp % find . -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered {} . \; && find . -type d -exec rm -r {} +
rm: refusing to remove "." or ".." directory: skipping "."
user@debian ~/tmp % tree -a
.
├── file1
├── file1.~1~
├── file1.~2~
├── file2
├── file2.~1~
├── file2.~2~
├── file3
├── file3.~1~
├── file3.~2~
├── .hidden
├── .hidden.~1~
└── .hidden.~2~

0 directories, 12 files
```

Comment: I really love this community. Thank you so much, kos!

Comment: this is a nice solution, but note it just works for two levels. If you would run it against `dir/subdir/subdir2/file`, the file would be moved to `dir/` instead of `dir/subdir/`. That is, it is moving to a predefined dir, not to the parent one of the given file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens to the 3rd files (i.e. there is no `file1~~`) ? Do they just get removed ?

Comment: @fedorqui I guess that's what OP asked for? "move all content of all subfolders to *a* top parent folder (recursively)" (mind the "a", it looks like he's referring to "the" single "top" parent folder)

Comment: I based my comment on the part when says: `move all content of all subfolders to a top parent folder (recursively)`. So it is unclear what the OP is asking if it says something different later on. To make this be recursive, you can use something like `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'd={}; d1=${d%/*}; echo $d ${d1%/*}' \;` and then adjust `mv`, etc.

Comment: @Ploutox Thank you very much for pointing this out, it seems like `mv` doesn't check if the "new" filename is already used by a file already present and just overwrites it. `--backup=numbered` avoids this

Comment: @Sebastian I've updated the command to remove the empty folders as well, which is something I didn't notice you asked for, although indeed Arronical addressed this already in its answer.

Comment: I don’t understand this discussion about moving `dir/subdir/subdir2/file` to `dir` versus `dir/subdir`.  The question says, (after the procedure is finished) “Parent folder we are standing in will contain no folders, just content of all of them.” — which clearly implies that files from all levels are supposed to be moved to the top-level directory (the directory where the command is being run).  Simply by *searching* `dir/subdir/subdir2`, this is a recursive solution.  `mv -b */* .` would be an example of a non-recursive solution.  (It’s also wrong, as it moves the subdirectories.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  But, if you just wanted to move each file up one level from where it is now (i.e., to the parent of the directory it’s in now), I believe that you could do that with `find . -mindepth 2 -type f -execdir mv --backup=numbered {} .. ";"`.  The `-execdir` action causes the command to run from the directory where the file is, with `{}` set to the filename only (i.e., not the pathname).  Use `-mindepth 2` to avoid moving files from the top-level directory to the directory *above that* (e.g., moving `/home/sebastian/.bashrc` to `/home`).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (I prefer `";"` over `\;` just as a matter of personal preference).  Either way, though, I’d be concerned about the order in which `find` searches the tree.  If you say `-depth`, it will work the tree from the bottom up, but is it guaranteed to work top down if you *don’t* say `-depth`?  What if it moves `dir/subdir/subdir2/file` to `dir/subdir`, and then it “finds” `dir/subdir/file`?  Will it then move it to `dir`?

Comment: @Scott I either tought it was clear that OP wanted to move all files in the top-level directory. However, on "If you say -depth, it will work the tree from the bottom up, but is it guaranteed to work top down if you don’t say -depth?": I'd say no. IME `find` processes hierarchies from top to bottom; adding to this the inode structure, expecially in such a complex case, and picturing a real world case in which folders and files in the hierarchy have been repeatedly created and deleted, might play a role, as it does, for one, when simply listing files (using `find`) in a single directory.

Answer (score 6):

1. To move all files recursively in the current directory, note that this will move all files into this directory (not their parent directories) :

   ```
   find . -type f -exec mv -i -t . {} +
   ```

Instead of `-i` you can use `--backup=numbered` as shown already by @kos.

2. To remove all empty directories :

   ```
   find . -type d -empty -delete
   ```

Read `man find` to get more idea.

Comment: If you use `cp`, the folders will never be empty

Comment: This does leave copies of all of the files in the directories though doesn't it? So there won't be any empty directories to delete. It's definitely safer than my suggestion though!

Comment: @Ploutox my bad..it was from my test..

Comment: @Arronical my bad..it was from my test..corrected ..

Comment: +1 but check Ploutox's [comment](http://askubuntu.com/users/169060/ploutox), there seems to be a bug in `mv` when using the `-b` option, using `--backup=[]` prevents that very dangerous thing to happen

Comment: @kos `cp` and `mv` both have the same behavior so i think they are designed this way..corrected..

Comment: Yes you're right, thinking about it again that's probably intended, in order to just keep the latest version

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you:

```
find . -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered "{}" . \; && find . -type d -empty -delete
```

It's 2 find commands the first one finds and moves the files, the second one will only run if the first command is successful and will remove the directories.

Thanks to Rinzwind for pointing out the danger of duplicate filenames, prompting me to add the `--backup=numbered` option originally used by Kos.

Comment: And if 2 files in 2 directories have the same name? as Kos mentioned: use "-b" option when moving ;)

Comment: Thank you, Arronical, works like it should! This will spare me lot of time in the future :-) Thanks again!

Comment: how about `find . -type d -empty -delete`?

Comment: `find ./* -type d -exec rm -r "{}" \;` this will remove all directories whether they are empty or not..

Comment: That seems even more sensible than starting an `-exec` @Ron

Comment: @heemayl that was my plan, though I'm in danger of assuming that all of the files moved as expected in the first part of the command. If they haven't, wouldn't the `&&` mean that the directory part of the command would not be executed?

Comment: @Arronical true, I just find `-empty` nice (and an additional check) :)

Comment: @Arronical Yeah..thats right..but what if OP wants to run the commands individually ? your command would only work as it is..

Comment: +1 but check Ploutox's [comment](http://askubuntu.com/users/169060/ploutox), there seems to be a bug in `mv` when using the `-b` option, using `--backup=[]` prevents that very dangerous thing to happen

Comment: Cheers @kos, I was mid-edit!

Comment: I was a little troubled when I saw the command `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -r {} +` in @kos’s answer, but I believe that it’s *probably* safe, because, *probably, **most*** versions of `rm` will refuse to remove **`.`** (the current directory).  `-empty` is a good way to handle that, but it (and `-delete`, for that matter) aren’t [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  A better answer might be `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec rm -r {} +`, using `-mindepth 1` to tell `find` not to look at **`.`** (but `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` aren’t standard either).  But `find ./* …` is wrong, because, unless you say `shopt -s dotglob`, that will not find “hidden directories” (e.g., `.subdir42`), and the question explicitly said that the answer “should work for hidden files and folders”.